# for $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{zw} = \sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> for $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{zw} = \sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$

I started by writing $z$ and $w$ in polar coordinates, and writing it out, giving another form for the question:
$$
\begin{align}
y &= r_1r_2cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) +  r_1r_2sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) i\\
y &= a + bi
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{zw} = \sqrt{r_1(cos(\theta_1)+isin(\theta_2))}\sqrt{r_2(cos(\theta_2)+isin(\theta_2))}
$$
but how to prove the original problem without just saying: square both sides?

Comment: If by $\sqrt{X}$ you denote a _specific_ square root of $X$, then the identity does not hold for all $z,w$, only for some.

Comment: What does $\sqrt z$ mean here? For example $\sqrt {2i}$ could be either of $1 \pm i$ and there is no immediate reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: It is said that even Euler got confused with $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\,\sqrt{b}$. Or did he? See [Euler's "mistake''? The radical product rule in historical perspective](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642191) (Amer. Math. Monthly 114 (2007), no. 4, 273–285).

Comment: The correct version of your statement should be $$|\sqrt{zw}|=|\sqrt z||\sqrt w|, \forall z,w\in C.$$

Comment: @Nilan: Why so? Proving the lengths to be the same does not mean I can immediatly decompose them into their original form right?

Comment: Are you actually putting downvotes to every answer you aren't 100% happy with? I am deleting my answer because I don't approve of such behaviour.

Comment: @5xum: Your assumption that WiseStrawberry is downvoting all the answers is incorrect. One way to tell is that WiseStrawberry's account has cast a total of 1 downvote.  Also, the account page doesn't show any numbers for recent votes; I'm not sure, but that may indicate they haven't voted today at all.

Comment: Note that $$\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-4}\not=\sqrt{-1\times -4}.$$

Comment: @JonasMeyer You're right, someone else is doing that. Still, it's highly unconstructive to post downvotes and not offer an answer of one's own.

Comment: @5xum: Your assumption that the same person has downvoted all of the answers is unfounded.  In fact I can ensure that it is incorrect in this case, but I don't want to get into it any further.

Comment: @JonasMeyer My point that it is not constructive to downvote and say nothing still stands.

Comment: i'm not downvoting anything.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry: The question is unclear.  What is your definition of square root of a complex number?  Are you referring to the sets of square roots, or choosing a particular branch?  There are limited circumstances in which the identity will hold.

Answer (score 1):

*Another correct formulation.*
A complex number may have two square-roots.  If you take any square-root of $w$ and multiply it by any square-root of $z$, the product will be a square-root of $zw$.

Answer (score -1):

This is very dangerous...

Even if you choose a consistent definition (e.g. $\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$), what happens when $z=i$ and $w=-i$?

Comment: This is unclear; the answer to your question depends on what values $\theta$ is assumed to hold.  E.g. if you are assuming $-\pi<\theta\leq \pi$, then with that definition and that example the identity would hold.  However, with $z=w=-1+i$ there will be trouble, or even $z=w=-1$.